# Please Solve this error i dont know what i am missing

Tags: android

/com.example.pawan.madc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.pawan.madc, PID: 23315
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pawan.madc/com.example.pawan.madc.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.example.pawan.madc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6100)

Comment: Start by posting the **FULL** logcat and your code (only the **relevant bits**.)

Comment: post your layout file

Answer (score 0):

Try to add support design library because fab button is design library component.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

Your activity theme also should be appropriate Theme.AppCompat theme. Also FAB requires colorAccent. Make sure you have them inside your styles.xml.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```